# How to append xml data into xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to convert collection class to xml data and append that xml data to xml file
here is my function'

```
  public void XmlWriter(List<Email> Femails)
    {
        string ErrorXmlFile = @"../../Retries.xml";
        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(ErrorXmlFile))
            {
                XmlSerializer xSeriz = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Email>));
                FileStream fs = File.Open(ErrorXmlFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                xSeriz.Serialize(fs, Femails);

            }
            else 
            {
                foreach(Email email in Femails)
                {
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(ErrorXmlFile);
                XmlNode xnode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ArrayOfEmail", null);
                XmlSerializer xSeriz = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Email));
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                xSeriz.Serialize(sw,email);
                xnode.InnerXml = Convert.ToString(sw);
                doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xnode);
                doc.Save(ErrorXmlFile);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

In the above function "femail" is parameter of a List, where Email is userdefind custom class.
First time it checks if the file is existing or not. If not then it works fine now but when i need to append data to my existing file it fails.

As per my above code it converts single Email object to xml data with  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>` with this tags which i want to remove before bind.

The output i got from my code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfEmail xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Email>
    <UtcDateTime>2013-01-23T10:09:48+05:30</UtcDateTime>
    <From>Rajendra Bhalekar &lt;rajendra.b000@gmail.com&gt;</From>
    <To>Mansha Suman &lt;asdmansha@gmail.com&gt;</To>
    <Subject>Ye dil sun raha hai jo mere dil ki hai sada ye...socha tha na maine......</Subject>
    <IDX>32a84ef7-31bf-4366-bcab-ec10b2f39bc6</IDX>
    <Body>
Hi Raj,

Dil pe mat le yaar dil pe mat le....
idx:32a84ef7-31bf-4366-bcab-ec10b2f39bc6

odhani chunariya tere naam ki - Pyar kiya to darna kya

sona sona telephone dhun pe hasne wali - hidustaniREPLY ABOVE THIS LINEdil
ibadat kar raha hai


Thanks &amp; regards,

Raj

</Body>
    <ExtractReplyText>Hi Raj,Dil pe mat le yaar dil pe mat le....idx:32a84ef7-31bf-4366-bcab-ec10b2f39bc6odhani chunariya tere naam ki - Pyar kiya to darna kya</ExtractReplyText>
  </Email>
  <ArrayOfEmail>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Email xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <UtcDateTime>2013-01-23T10:09:48+05:30</UtcDateTime>
  <From>Rajendra Bhalekar &lt;rajendra.b000@gmail.com&gt;</From>
  <To>Mansha Suman &lt;asdmansha@gmail.com&gt;</To>
  <Subject>Ye dil sun raha hai jo mere dil ki hai sada ye...socha tha na maine......</Subject>
  <IDX>32a84ef7-31bf-4366-bcab-ec10b2f39bc6</IDX>
  <Body>
Hi Raj,

Dil pe mat le yaar dil pe mat le....
idx:32a84ef7-31bf-4366-bcab-ec10b2f39bc6

odhani chunariya tere naam ki - Pyar kiya to darna kya

sona sona telephone dhun pe hasne wali - hidustaniREPLY ABOVE THIS LINEdil
ibadat kar raha hai


Thanks &amp; regards,

Raj

</Body>
  <ExtractReplyText>Hi Raj,Dil pe mat le yaar dil pe mat le....idx:32a84ef7-31bf-4366-bcab-ec10b2f39bc6odhani chunariya tere naam ki - Pyar kiya to darna kya</ExtractReplyText>
</Email></ArrayOfEmail>
</ArrayOfEmail>
```

Which is not as i am expecting. Please suggest me required corrections.

Comment: Hi, your question is a little unclear.  "it fails" - how does it fail, exception?  "not i am expecting" - what were you expecting? Thanks

Comment: It fails means its not giving proper results valid xml document. for example   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><parentnode><node> </node></parentndoe> its my orginal xml doc ok. when i bind new node to my xml doc its bind as per given below   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> <parentnode><node></node> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><parentnode><node></node></parentnode></parentnode>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problam is solve now and this code is working for me

```
public void XmlWriter(List<Email> Femails)
{
    #region On Error Retry and retrycount with xml file

    string ErrorXmlFile = @"../../Retries.xml";
    try
    {
        if (!File.Exists(ErrorXmlFile))
        {
            XmlSerializer xSeriz = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Email>));
            FileStream fs = File.Open(ErrorXmlFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            xSeriz.Serialize(fs, Femails);
            foreach (Email email in Femails)
            {
                SaveAttachment(email);
            }

        }
        else 
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(ErrorXmlFile);

            foreach (Email email in Femails)
            {
                XmlNode xnode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "BLACKswastik", null);
                XmlSerializer xSeriz = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Email));
                XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                ns.Add("", "");
                XmlWriterSettings writtersetting = new XmlWriterSettings();
                writtersetting.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
                StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();
                using (XmlWriter xmlwriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(stringwriter, writtersetting))
                {
                    xSeriz.Serialize(xmlwriter, email, ns);
                }
                xnode.InnerXml = stringwriter.ToString();
                XmlNode bindxnode = xnode.SelectSingleNode("Email");
                doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(bindxnode);
                SaveAttachment(email);
            }
            doc.Save(ErrorXmlFile);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    #endregion
}
```